# How to use google perf tools

Tags: profiling, gperftools

I just started using google performance tools (`google-perftools` and `libgoogle-perftools4` packages in ubuntu), I swear that I'm googling for around a day and I didn't find an answer!!
The problem is that I do not get the result for ALL of my functions with CPU profiling. This is my code:

```
#include "gperftools/profiler.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
void bar()
{
        int a,b,c,d,j,k;
        a=0;
        int z=0;
        b = 1000;
        while(z < b)
        {
                while (a < b)
                {
                        d = sin(a);
                        c = cos(a);
                        j = tan(a);
                        k = tan(a);
                        k = d * c + j *k;
                        a++;
                }
                a = 0;
                z++;
        }
}
void foo()
{
        cout << "hey " << endl;
}

int main()
{
        ProfilerStart("/home/mohammad/gperf/dump.txt");

        int a = 1000;
        while(a--){foo();}
        bar();
        ProfilerFlush();
        ProfilerStop();
}
```

Compiled as `g++ test.cc -lprofiler -o a.out`

this is how I run the code:

```
CPUPROFILE=dump.txt ./a.out
```

I've also tried this:

```
CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY=10000 LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libprofiler.so.0.3.0 CPUPROFILE=dump.txt ./a.out
```

And this is what I get from `google-pprof --text a.out dump.txt`:

```
Using local file ./a.out.
Using local file ./dump.txt.
Total: 22 samples
8  36.4%  36.4%        8  36.4% 00d8cb04
6  27.3%  63.6%        6  27.3% bar
3  13.6%  77.3%        3  13.6% __cos (inline)
2   9.1%  86.4%        2   9.1% 00d8cab4
1   4.5%  90.9%        1   4.5% 00d8cab6
1   4.5%  95.5%        1   4.5% 00d8cb06
1   4.5% 100.0%        1   4.5% __write_nocancel
0   0.0% 100.0%        3  13.6% __cos
```

But there is no information about the foo function!

my system information:
ubuntu 12.04
g++ 4.6.3

Thats all!

Comment: You said you tried "CPUPROFILE_FREQUENC=10000" but that is missing a Y, so if actual (and ignored) then you might not have enough samples to make the tiny foo show up.

Comment: You're looking at CPU time, not wall-clock time. The amount of CPU time `foo` uses is almost nothing. All it does is call library functions that do I/O, and CPU samples don't happen during I/O.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TL;DR: `foo` is to fast and small to get profiling events, run it 100 more times. Frequency setting was with typo, and `pprof` will not sample more often than CONFIG_HZ (usually 250). It is better to switch to more modern Linux `perf` profiler ([tutorial from its authors](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial), [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perf_%28Linux%29)).

Long version:

Your `foo` function is just too short and simple - just call two functions. Compiled the test with `g++ test.cc -lprofiler -o test.s -S -g`, with filtering of `test.s` with `c++filt` program to make c++ names readable:

```
foo():
.LFB972:
        .loc 1 27 0
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .loc 1 28 0
        movl    $.LC0, %esi
        movl    std::cout, %edi
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
        movl    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&), %esi
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))
        .loc 1 29 0
        popq    %rbp
        ret
.LFE972:
        .size   foo(), .-foo()
```

So, to see it in the profile you should run `foo` for more times, changing `int a = 1000;` in main to something much greater, like 10000 or better 100000 (as did I for the test).

Also you may fix the incorrect "`CPUPROFILE_FREQUENC=10000`" to correct `CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY` (note the `Y`). I should say that 10000 is too high setting for CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY, because it usually may only generate 1000 or 250 events per second depending on kernel configuration `CONFIG_HZ` (most 3.x kernels have 250, check `grep CONFIG_HZ= /boot/config*`).  And default setting for CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY in pprof is 100.

I tested different values of CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY: 100000, 10000, 1000, 250 with bash script on Ubuntu 14.04

```
for a in 100000 100000 10000 10000 1000 1000 300 300 250 250; do 
   echo -n "$a "; 
   CPUPROFILE_FREQUENCY=$a CPUPROFILE=dump$a.txt ./test >/dev/null;
done
```

And the results were the same 120-140 events and runtime of every ./test around 0.5 seconds, so cpuprofiler from google-perftools can't do more events per second for single thread, than CONFIG_HZ set in kernel (my has 250).

```
100000 PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 124/1/6584
100000 PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 134/0/7864
10000 PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 125/0/7488
10000 PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 123/0/6960
1000 PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 134/0/6264
1000 PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 125/2/7272
300 PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 137/2/7984
300 PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 126/0/7216
250 PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 123/3/6680
250 PROFILE: interrupts/evictions/bytes = 137/2/7352
```

With original a=1000 `foo` and cout's functions runs too fast to get any profiling event (even on 250 events/s) on them in every run, so you have no `foo`, nor any Input/Output functions. In small amount of runs, the `__write_nocancel` may got sampling event, and then `foo`  and I/O functions form libstdc++ will be reported (somewhere not in the very top, so use `--text` option of `pprof` or `google-pprof`) with zero self event count, and non-zero child event count:

```
 ....
   1   0.9%  99.1%        1   0.9% __write_nocancel
 ....
   0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.9% _IO_new_file_overflow
   0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.9% _IO_new_file_write
   0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.9% __GI__IO_putc
   0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.9% foo
   0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.9% new_do_write
   0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.9% std::endl
   0   0.0% 100.0%        1   0.9% std::ostream::put
```

With `a=100000`, foo is still too short and fast to get own events, but I/O functions got several. This is list I grepped from long `--text` output:

```
  34  24.6%  24.6%       34  24.6% __write_nocancel

   1   0.7%  95.7%       35  25.4% __GI__IO_fflush
   1   0.7%  96.4%        1   0.7% __GI__IO_putc
   1   0.7%  97.8%        2   1.4% std::operator<< 
   1   0.7%  98.6%       36  26.1% std::ostream::flush
   1   0.7%  99.3%        2   1.4% std::ostream::put
   0   0.0% 100.0%       34  24.6% _IO_new_file_sync
   0   0.0% 100.0%       34  24.6% _IO_new_file_write
   0   0.0% 100.0%       40  29.0% foo

   0   0.0% 100.0%       34  24.6% new_do_write

   0   0.0% 100.0%        2   1.4% std::endl
```

Functions with zero own counters seen only thanks to `pprof` capability of reading call chains (it knows who calls the functions which got sample, if frame info is not omitted).

I can also recommend more modern, more capable (both software and hardware events, up to 5 kHz frequency or more; both user-space and kernel profiling) and better supported profiler, the Linux `perf` profiler ([tutorial from its authors](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial), [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perf_%28Linux%29)).

There are results from `perf` with `a=10000`:

```
$ perf record  ./test3  >/dev/null
 ... skip some perf's spam about inaccessibility of kernel symbols 
 ... note the 3 kHz frequency here VVVV
Lowering default frequency rate to 3250. 
Please consider tweaking /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_max_sample_rate.
[ perf record: Woken up 1 times to write data ]
[ perf record: Captured and wrote 0.078 MB perf.data (~3386 samples) ]
```

To see text report from `perf.data` output file I'll use less (because `perf report` by default starts interactive profile browser):

```
$ perf report |less
... skip some extra info about the machine, kernel, and perf starting command
# Samples: 1K of event 'cycles'
# Event count (approx.): 1155264208
# Overhead   Command   Shared Object          Symbol
    41.94%    test3  libm-2.19.so         [.] __tan_sse2                                                                                                                                                                    
    16.95%    test3  libm-2.19.so         [.] __sin_sse2    
    13.40%    test3  libm-2.19.so         [.] __cos_sse2                                                                                                                                                                    
     4.93%    test3  test3                [.] bar()                                                                                                                                                                         
     2.90%    test3  libc-2.19.so         [.] __GI___libc_write    
....
     0.20%    test3  test3                [.] foo()
```

Or `perf report -n | less` to see raw event (sample) counters:

```
# Overhead       Samples  Command        Shared Object 
    41.94%           663    test3  libm-2.19.so         [.] __tan_sse2                                                                                                                                                                    
    16.95%           268    test3  libm-2.19.so         [.] __sin_sse2   
    13.40%           212    test3  libm-2.19.so         [.] __cos_sse2                                                                                                                                                                    
     4.93%            78    test3  test3                [.] bar()                                                                                                                                                                         
     2.90%            62    test3  libc-2.19.so         [.] __GI___libc_write     
 ....
     0.20%             4    test3  test3                [.] foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting LD_PRELOAD to just

> LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libprofiler.so

It [looks like there are problems](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/issues/487) when passing a shared library that doesn't end in suffix .so.